# TCP connection only works one way

Tags: c#, tcp

I'm building a Client-Server application that is supposed to send files from one PC (server) to another PC (client) as soon as they appear. If I connect the client to the running server, I get an error because the server is unreachable. However, if I run the client on the PC that is supposed to be the server and vice versa, it works as intended. It also works if I run both server and client on the same PC so I assume the problem is not in the code.

Is there some sort of configuration in C# or Windows (I'm running 64bit Windows 7 on both PCs) that needs to be enabled (which currently is only enabled on one of the PCs)? Or could there be some sort of problem with the ports? I'm using a fixed port for the server and random ports for the client.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance :)

Comment: Are you sure the port isn't being blocked?

Comment: if you're working for a company you should check with the infrastructure team to see if there is a firewall issue, you might need to be allowed access

Comment: Its either a firewall blocking incoming connections on your server ot a routing issue (i.e. NAT) so that your client can't reach the servers ip directly (you can try to ping the server from your client)

Comment: I think I need to be more specific. I'm doing this as an exercise and am running the application on my home network, both PCs are in the same subnet so it shouldn't be a routing issue. I am not blocking any ports intentionally. I don't think ports are blocked anyway because if I swap server and client (run them on the other PC) it works.

Comment: I think one of the computers might just be blocking ports with the Windows firewall.